# Ansible Symbolic Link Task Role Failure

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and executing the following ansible task:

```
- name: Create symbolic links
  file:
    src:  "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: "{{ jboss_usr }}"
    group: "{{ jboss_grp }}"
    state: link
  with_items:
    - { src: "/apps/etc/jboss",     dest: "/etc/jboss" }
    - { src: "/apps/var/log/jboss", dest: "/var/log/jboss" }
```

And I got the following error:

```
2018-12-21 21:27:23,469 p=15185 u=ex_sam |  failed: [hostname.x] (item={u'dest': u'/etc/jboss', u'src': u'/apps/etc/jboss'}) => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null, 
            "backup": null, 
            "content": null, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": "/etc/jboss", 
            "diff_peek": null, 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": true, 
            "force": true, 
            "group": "jboss", 
            "mode": null, 
            "original_basename": null, 
            "owner": "jboss", 
            "path": "/etc/jboss", 
            "recurse": false, 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": "/apps/etc/jboss", 
            "state": "link", 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "validate": null
        }
    }, 
    "item": {
        "dest": "/etc/jboss-as", 
        "src": "/apps/etc/jboss"
    }, 
    "msg": "Error while linking: [Errno 13] Permission denied", 
    "path": "/etc/jboss-as", 
    "state": "absent"
}
```

I am trying to find out why the symbolic link creation failed.

I read the following:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#id6

I says the "changed" attribute is a boolean indicating if the task had to make changes.

But, there are lots of null parameters in the invocation:module_args elements of the json

Does that mean the values are really “null” or they are being set to a default value?

I have looked into the ansible documentation and I am not sure if the invocation:module_args null values are representative of the outcome of the trying to create the symbolic link i.e. are the null input or output of executing the tasks.

I think some of the nulls are defaults, but will appreciate some helpful comments on the possible relation between the json returned in my ansible error log and the actual "Error while linking: [Errno 13] Permission denied".

Thanks all for you anticipated help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, is the permissions on /etc. So probably you need to add the option:

```
become: true
```

To your task.

Comment: Yes, I know it's permissions denied. But, that script used to work on other VMs. Where should the become:true be added and what is it's function? Also, what does module_args represent in the error msg json returned after executing task.

Comment: I have seen that some existing play have the become:true , followed by become_user : root . I am guessing I will be prompted for root password when I execute the ansible task? I can't still find what the module args stands for though. Any ideas ?